# How to get fast writing with Geopandas & Fiona?

Tags: gdal, geopandas, fiona

I have a GeoDataFrame with 1,2M records, and want to write it into a GeoPackage file. Currently, it takes >20 minutes, and, as I calculated, average write speed is 100 recs/sec.

As I read in the comments, the problem is that Fiona frequently locks and unlocks the sqlite database of GeoPackage.

Is there a way to improve write performance?

- building Fiona on the machine?
- opening the file in a specific mode?
- setting environment parameters for Fiona & GDAL?

QGIS writes the same amount of records about 10 times faster, I'd be happy to see a similar improvement.

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, but I also have a 18.10 one.

Comment: What version of GeoPandas and Fiona do you use? As I understand, you opened issues in both those packages last year that led to improvements in their latest versions.

Comment: Fiona 1.8.0, Geopandas 0.4.0

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I checked with a test dataframe: it is now much faster than with GeoPandas 0.3 / Fiona 1.7, but still way slower than QGIS. Worth a further investigation.

Comment: I opened new issues https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/863 and https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/685 to track this. Certainly on the GeoPandas side it should be possible to improve it significantly.

Comment: On the geopandas side, a significant performance improvement has been merged (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/864), which will end up in the upcoming release.